# How to add rows based on a condition in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a Training Planning database with this template:

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig2K3.png)

The idea is to create a column called "Month" and for each training add a row with the same data but for a different month. Something like this: [Table Example rows added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIOLZ.png)

The point is that I have more than 2k training and it is totally unproductive to do this manually.

Do you guys know any script in Python that can add these rows?

Comment: Can you post your code attempting to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Initialize an empty list
rows = []

# Iterate over a range of numbers
for i in range(10):
    # Check if the number is even
    if i % 2 == 0:
        # If the number is even, add it to the list
        rows.append(i)

# Print the resulting list
print(rows)  # Output: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```